# How can i write a MySQL query in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

How can I write the following mysql query in cakephp:

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2008-12-23' AND '2008-12-25';

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Cake's ORM, it would look something like this (where Model is the name of your model, usually a singularized version of your table name):

```
$this->Model->find('all', array('conditions' => array(
    'Model.date BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array('2008-12-23', '2008-12-25')));
```

Check here for more details:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html